# builder cannot be applied android (Alertdialog)

Tags: android, this, android-alertdialog

I created an AlertDialog that shows 3 buttons in Android Studio but an error appears on the reserved word "this". In the attached image, the source code can be viewed in greater detail.

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

How can I solve this error?

```
private void muestraDialogo2() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder2.setTitle("Lista de muestra");
    builder2.setMessage("Tipos de muestra");
    builder2.setCancelable(false);

    builder2.setPositiveButton("Imprimir todas", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Imprimiendo...*", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    });
```

Comment: You might want to go into a bit more detail. Provide what you are doing, why you are doing it, etc.

Comment: Why you put this method inside OnClickListener anonymous class body? Do you know java?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the wrong parameter in the AlertDialog.Builder constructor. at line 50, the this object refers to a View.OnClickListener class and not a valid context object.

Change the line:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

for

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main3Activity.this);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I corrected the error.

Comment: @Airbeat Great! please accept my answer!